# creating a google spreadsheet using google spreadsheet api in java

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

Is there provision to create **google spreadsheet** using google spreadsheet api in **java.**

I could find only .**NET** code in **google developer site**.

**PS**:Although there is retrieving spreadsheet  api in JAVA but no creating API i could find.

Would be great help if someone clarified on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that C# was made using Java syntax,
 Have you attempted to translate the C# code you found on the API docs to Java?  I'm sure the libraries included are transferrable.
EDIT:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#adding_a_worksheet

You are able to switch to "Java" code using the tabs.